# turning existing application into a shopify app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app

I have an existing web application with ruby on rails and I think it would be perfect as a shopify app. I did everything (parnter account, development store, etc.) and when I created a test app with `shopify app create rails` , I was able to add the app to my store. However, how do I do that when the project already exists? When I try to run `shopify app serve` I get the error message

```
┏━━ Error ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃ ✗ You are not in a Shopify app project
┃ ⭑ Run shopify app create to create your app
┃ 
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

But if I were to run this command, it would create a new project, which I don't want since I already have the project. I only want to turn it into a shopify app project, but I haven't found an answer whether this is possible and if yes, how to do it.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the Shopify CLI. It is handy when you start from scratch but as you already have a running web app, you rather need to directly use the dedicated [Shopify API gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api).